# Storing result of a thread or process with concurrent.futures

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency

I'm writing a utility I can use to check ports on many subnets. Currently I'm adding my results to a csv file and then sorting the file. I would like to instead add my results to a single list and then output the list so I'm doing fewer file open/close operations. I cannot seem to figure out how to make my results persist between threads. Below is my code:

```
import csv
import test_ports
import pandas
import ipaddress
import concurrent.futures
import time
import os


class check_subnets(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.tested_list = []

    def setup(self, l_subnets):
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
            executor.map(self.subnet_search, l_subnets)
        return self.tested_list

    def subnet_search(self, sub):
        print("Testing the " + sub + " subnet.")
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=16) as executor2:
            executor2.map(self.ip_search, ipaddress.IPv4Network(sub))

    def ip_search(self, ip):
        test = test_ports.TestPort()
        s_ip_addr = str(ip)
        print("Tested " + s_ip_addr)
        test_ssh = test.test_ssh(s_ip_addr)
        test_rdp = test.test_rdp(s_ip_addr)
        this_list = [s_ip_addr, test_ssh, test_rdp]
        self.tested_list.append(this_list)
        with open('tested.csv', 'a') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow(this_list)
        file.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    subnets = pandas.read_csv('hosts.csv')
    list_subnets = subnets['Subnet'].values.tolist()
    fields = ['IP_Addr', "SSH(22)", "RDP(443)"]
    with open('tested.csv', 'w') as f:
        write = csv.writer(f)
        write.writerow(fields)
    f.close()
    t0 = time.time()
    checker = check_subnets()
    results = checker.setup(list_subnets)
    print(results)
    t1 = time.time()
    print(t1-t0)
    with open("tested.csv", 'r',newline='') as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)
        data = sorted(csv_input, key=lambda row: (row['IP_Addr']))
    f_input.close()

    with open("sorted.csv", 'w', newline='') as f_output:
        csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=csv_input.fieldnames)
        csv_output.writeheader()
        csv_output.writerows(data)
    f_output.close()
    if os.path.exists("tested.csv"):
        os.remove("tested.csv")
    else:
        print("The file does not exist")
```

I'm using the class to try and create some kind of location each method would see. I have a feeling the class-specific tested_list is not available to each thread, rather each thread is seeing one instance of tested_list and not a shared list.

The test_ports module is just a wrapper for some socket operations.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that there is a small difference in concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor
and
concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

ThreadPoolExecutor is doing exactly what I wanted, preserving data between threads. New code looks like this:

```
import csv
import test_ports
import pandas
import ipaddress
import concurrent.futures
import time


class check_subnets(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.tested_list = []

    def setup(self, l_subnets):
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
            executor.map(self.subnet_search, l_subnets)
        return self.tested_list

    def subnet_search(self, sub):
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=16) as executor2:
            executor2.map(self.ip_search, ipaddress.IPv4Network(sub))

    def ip_search(self, ip):
        test = test_ports.TestPort()
        s_ip_addr = str(ip)
        test_ssh = test.test_ssh(s_ip_addr)
        test_rdp = test.test_rdp(s_ip_addr)
        this_list = [s_ip_addr, test_ssh, test_rdp]
        self.tested_list.append(this_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    subnets = pandas.read_csv('hosts.csv')
    list_subnets = subnets['Subnet'].values.tolist()
    t0 = time.time()
    checker = check_subnets()
    results = checker.setup(list_subnets)
    t1 = time.time()
    print(t1-t0)
    sorted_list = (sorted(results, key=lambda x: x[0]))
    fields = ['IP_Addr', "SSH(22)", "RDP(443)"]
    with open('tested.csv', 'w') as f:
        write = csv.writer(f)
        write.writerow(fields)
        write.writerows(sorted_list)
    f.close()
```

The end result is a sorted list of opened and closed ssh and rdp ports.